# If $\sin(A)=\frac{3}{5}$ with A in quadrant II, and tan(A)=-1, with A in quadrant IV. Find the following values:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $\sin(A)=\frac{3}{5}$ with A in quadrant II, and tan(A)=-1, with A in quadrant IV. Find the following values:

a) Sec(A)=$\frac{5}{3}$

b) cos(A+B)

c) sin(2B)

d) Sin (A/2)=$\frac{3}{10}$

I'm having a hard time answering b and c,because I do not know what B is. Do you think its a typo in the problem?

Also can anyone confirm my answer for a and d?

Comment: For (d) you have to use something like the half-angle identity, which is $$\sin(\frac{x}{2})=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(x)}{2}}$$. You cannot simply say $\sin(\frac{x}{2})=\frac{\sin(x)}{2}$. Also, are you sure $B$ is not defined elsewhere in the problem? Otherwise, maybe you should express answers in terms of trigonometric ratios whose arguments involve only $B$.

Comment: Should it say "$\tan B = -1$? If not, what is $B$? It's impossible for $\sin A = 3/5$ and $\tan A = -1$.

Comment: I got +/- $\frac{3}{\sqrt(10)}$ for d and yeah I think it should say tan$B=-1$

Comment: Assuming its $tan(B)$ apply $cos(A+B)=cos(A)cos(B)-sin(A)sin(B)$ in (b). And $sin(2B)=2sin(B)cos(B)$ in c.

Answer (score 1):

In the diagram, the point $(-4,3)$ in quadrant II lies on the terminal of any standard angle $A$ for which $\sin(A)=\dfrac{5}{4}$. Note the triangle having this point and the origin as vertices and its right angle vertex on the $x$-axis.

This triangle has hypotenuse$=5$, adjacent side$=-4$ and opposite side$=5$ and may be used to find any of the six trigonometric functions of $A$.

So we see immediately that $\sec(A)=-\dfrac{5}{4}$.

The smaller triangle contains the point $(1,-1)$ in quadrant IV. This point lies on the terminal side of angle $B$ since we are told that $B$ is in quadrant IV and that $\tan(B)=-1$. One may find all six trigonometric functions of any standard angle with terminal side containing the point $(1,-1)$ by using the ratios of the sides of this triangle. Note that the hypotenuse equals $\sqrt{2}$, the adjacent side$=1$ and the opposite side$=-1$.

**It is important to note which sides are negative!**

Remember that the hypotenuse is **never negative** and the sign of the adjacent side is always the sign of $x$ and the opposite side is always the sign of $y$, depending upon which quadrant the angle is in.

Now we are ready to find $\cos(A+B)$ using the addition identity for cosine which will require that we know the sines and cosines of both $A$ and $B$ which we will read from the sides of the two triangles.

1. $\sin(A)=\dfrac{3}{5}$ (which actually was given)
2. $\cos(A)=-\frac{4}{5}$
3. $\sin(B)=\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}=-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$
4. $\cos(B)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Then using the Law of Cosines we obtain

\begin{eqnarray}
 \cos(A+B)&=&\cos(A)\cos(B)-\sin(A)\sin(B)\\
&=&-\frac{4}{5}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\dfrac{3}{5}\cdot\dfrac{-\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
&=&-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{10}
\end{eqnarray}

To find $\sin(2B)$ we need the double angle identity for sine:

$$ \sin(2B)=2\sin(B)\cos(B)=2\cdot\dfrac{-\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=-1 $$

To find $\sin(A/2)$ we need the half-angle formula for sine:

$$ \sin(A/2)=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos(A)}{2}}=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{1-\dfrac{-4}{5}}{2}}=\pm\dfrac{3\sqrt{10}}{10}$$

Note that the angle $\dfrac{A}{2}$ can lie in either quadrant I or quadrant III, so the sine could be either positive or it could be negative.

[image: Angle diagrams]